# Pandas df conditionals: changing value name if pd.value_counts is less than something

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, rename

I have this table with models df['model'] and

`pd.value_counts(df2['model'].values, sort=True)`

returns this:

```
'''
MONSTER        331
MULTISTRADA    134
HYPERMOTARD     69
SCRAMBLER       63
SUPERSPORT      31
              ... 
900              1
T-MAX            1
FC               1
GTS              1
SCOUT            1
Length: 75, dtype: int64
'''
```

I want to rename all the values in df2['model'] that have count <5 into 'OTHER'.
Please can anyone help me, how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You first can get a list of the categories you want to change to other with the first line of code. It takes your functiona and selects the rows which meet the condicion you want (in this case less than 5 occurences).

Then you select the dataframe and just select the rows whose model cell is in the list of categories you want to substitute and change te value to 'OTHER'.

```
other_classes = data['model'].value_counts()[data['model'].value_counts() < 5].index

data['model'][data['model'].isin(other_classes)] = 'OTHER'
```

Hope it helps

Comment: While this might answer the question, you might want to consider adding some comments to help people understand your answer

Comment: Thank you Pablo and yatu! When I entered your suggestion I got this error back: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-998ad2c54be2> in <module>
----> 1 other_classes = pd[pd.value_counts(df2['model'].values, sort=True) < 5].index
      2 
      3 pd[pd['model'].isin(other_classes)] = 'OTHER'

TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable

Comment: okey sorry, probably youre using 'import pandas as pd' and we're calling the module, raising an error. Try to substitute pd with the name of your dataframe. I edit the code so it looks cleaner

Comment: already did, with all permutations. still getting TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-1919bebebde4> in <module>
----> 1 other_classes = pd[pd.value_counts(df2['model'].values, sort=True) < 5].index
      2 
      3 df2[df2['model'].isin(other_classes)] = 'OTHER'

TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Try with the code i edited and replace data with the name of your DataFrame.

Comment: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is not at all elegant or pythonic, but this worked in the end:

```
df_pooled_other = df_final.assign(freq=df_final.groupby('model name')['model name'].transform('count'))\
  .sort_values(by=['freq','model name', 'Age in months_x_x'],ascending=[False,True, True])

df_pooled_other['model name'] = np.where(df_pooled_other['freq'] <= 5, 'Other', df_pooled_other['model name'])
```